# Reshaping data frame to extract specific results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'0': [2154,799,1023,4724], '1': [27, 2981, 952,797],'2':[4905,569,4767,569]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and

```
d={'PART_NO': ['J661-03982','661-08913', '922-8972','661-00352','661-06291',''], 'PART_NO_ENCODED': [2154,799,1023,27,569]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to get the corresponding `part_no` for each row in `df1` so the resulting data frame should look like this:

```
d={'PART_NO': ['J661-03982','661-00352',''], 'PART_NO_ENCODED': [2154,27,4905]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far, and read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `reindex`(after `set_index`)

```
df2.set_index('PART_NO_ENCODED').reindex(df1.iloc[0,:]).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'PART_NO_ENCODED'})
Out[242]: 
   PART_NO_ENCODED     PART_NO
0             2154  J661-03982
1               27   661-00352
2             4905         NaN
```

Comment: I want it to be flexible such that I can get the Part_No for all the rows in the first data frame.

Comment: @sayo what you mean get part

Comment: In this case we should always hardcode the value of df1.iloc[0,:] or df1.iloc[1:,] I want to know if there is a way I get for all rows the corresponding part_no

Comment: @sayo look at replace